# How to convert exe application to jar file?

Tags: java, jar, exe, launch4j

I have exe file called Myapp.exe. Now I want to convert .exe to jar file. That jar file should also work in NON JAVA system. I don't have any idea to implement it. Can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: _jar file should work in NON JAVA system_ ?

Comment: What do you mean by NON JAVA system

Comment: How can you think that a JAR, which is a Java archive, will work on a non-Java system?

Comment: *"That jar file should work in NON JAVA system also"* - Can't be done (easily or reliability). Much of what's required to run the byte code is the JVM, so you've need to wrap the JVM up as well.

Comment: If jar has to run on NON-java system, who will run it then?

Comment: This is impossible. Why do you want to do this? What do you hope to gain by doing this?

Comment: See also: [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331777/how-to-bundle-jre-inside-jar-and-how-to-run-a-jar)

Answer (score 3):

Direct conversion not available !!!
because they are in entirely different platforms.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Meeting your requirements is **impossible** for two reasons.

1) You cannot change an EXE to a JAR file.

2) You cannot run a JAR file on a system that doesn't have Java installed.

If you want to run something on a (Windows) system with no Java installation, it needs to be an EXE ... or something else that doesn't *require* Java.

(It might help if you explained why you think you need to do this.  Perhaps there is an alternative set of requirements that are not impossible to meet.)

---

> why i am doing all those stubs is for making my jar has to work in java not installed system.

It needs to be an EXE then!

> I have an jar.It is working fine in java installed system.My task is to Bundle jre inside jar(Not along with jar(i.e we can put jre and jar in same folder to run a jar as given in following url mindfiresolutions.com/… ))Because i have to give jar file only to client,in such a way that they can use this Myapp.jar in non java system also.But,i don't know how to bundle jre inside jar.I Don't how to run jre inside jar?

Ermm ...

> Is it possible?

No.  You *cannot* embed a JRE inside a JAR file in any way that would allow it (the JAR file) to run your Java code *without* first installing Java.  (And installing Java would defeat the purpose of embedding the JRE ... of course.)

But what you *can* do is create an EXE file which has a JRE and a JAR embedded in it.  And there are tools for doing this.  Here's the canonical Question on how to do it:

- [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

---

I think you need to read the Oracle documentation on what a JAR file really is, and how Java programs are normally executed.  That will help you understand what is feasible ... and what is nonsensical.

Comment: why i am doing all those stubs is for making my jar has to work in java not installed system.I have an jar.It is working fine in java installed system.My task is to Bundle jre inside jar(Not along with jar(i.e we can put jre and jar in same folder to run a jar as given in following url http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Run-jar-without-jre-on-windows-machine-76.php ))Because i have to give jar file only to client,in such a way that they can use this Myapp.jar in non java system also.But,i don't know how to bundle jre inside jar.I Don't how to run jre inside jar?Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir.. We can convert jar to .exe using tools like launch4j,etc.. I did it using launch4j tool and converted jar to exe.. and it is working fine.. Since,jre will bundled inside jar.. But,i must give jar file only to client.. Is there any way to bundle?

Comment: @user2155502 Not possible. A jar file is not magic. It is (literally) just a zip file containing .class files and other program resources. On its own, a jar cannot do anything. To be useful, it **needs** another program, such as the JRE or a launcher.